# Diff between Dotfuscator (PreEmptive solutions) & Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, dotfuscator, preemptive

I am trying to find a way to track the usage of some desktop applications and came across PreEmptive solutions and application insights and I still can't see clearly the difference in their perimeter, maybe I have the wrong impression but I feel like app. insights is "included" in what PreEmptive solutions offers, can I someone help me see the difference ?
Thks

Answer (score 0):

As with many usage analytics solutions, there is a large body of features/capabilities that are common (at least from 10K feet), and have many smaller differences when examined closely. 
However, there are few fundamental differences in approaches between App Insights and Preemptive:

1. AI is SaaS offering, Preemptive is a "box" product (I believe they are also offer cloud-hosted version). This also assumes different pricing models
2. Main instrumentation model for Preemptive is through code injection (potentially as part of obfuscation process). AI offers a sophisticated SDK and tight integration into Visual Studio IDE. Preemptive also has an SDK
3. AI offers Usage Analytics as part of the broader Application Performance and Analytics offering. AI is capable of capturing a wider range of telemetry information, including traces, exceptions (Preemptive does it too), metrics, dependencies, etc. and also enables both metric and log analyst. Preemptive is more focused